# How can I add a field to existing mapping with values in other fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

Current Mapping field is

```
      ...
      "latitude": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      ...
```

I wish to add a field 'location' using those data in latitude & longitude field. How can I implement?

```
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to add and populate data for new fields in the existing index.

The only way you can achieve it by `reindexing` data into new index.

Let's say you have an index(`source-index`) **test-geo-index** with two fields(not restricted to two fields for easy understanding purpose I took only 2 fields) `latitude` and `longitude` as shown below:

```
PUT test-geo-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "test-geo-type": {
      "properties": {
        "longitute": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "latitude": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create a new index(`dest-index`) **test-geo-updated-index** with the above mapping and  **location** field and populate data into it by using **elasticsearch _reindex API**.

```
PUT test-geo-updated-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "test-geo-type": {
      "properties": {
        "longitute": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "latitude": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Elasticsearch ReIndex API:**

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "test-geo-index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "test-geo-updated-index"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.location=ctx._source.latitude + \",\" + ctx._source.longitude"
  }
}
```

You can read more about Reindex API [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex)

Comment: Thank you so much!